# Jquery Validation Required for Multiple Checkbox with Multiples ID like ID1, ID2, ID3

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I had a "I AGREE" form with XX fields with checkboxes.

This fields come from a SQL table and will be selected or created by the admin.

The Admin can create as many as he wants.

All checkboxes must be required.

There is any way to check and require all checkboxes with one Jquery Rule?

```
        "agree[]": {
            required : true,
        },


<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" role="form" action="#" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label mLabelText"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 form-space checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="agree1" name="agree[]" value="1">
        CONDITION 1  
        </label>  
        </div>
      </div>   

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label mLabelText"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 form-space checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="agree2" name="agree[]" value="2">
        CONDITION 2  
        </label>  
        </div>
      </div>
```

I try this - but Jquery only requires ONE checkbox, not All.

**** Because I need a "dynamic rule" for all checkboxes - I think this will be the best way to do this..

tks a lot!

Comment: ID should be unique use class

Comment: hi @pekka ID is unique. The validation check the "name" value. tks a lot.

Comment: your title is saying something different! :) Anyway @Pekka is right. Give all the checkboxes the same class and use that to reference your jquery to check if the checkboxes are selected or to manipulate them in any other way (eg. to select/deselect all).

Comment: Hi @LelioFaieta. Tks! you are right about the title. My mistake - I dont know anything about Jquery/JS - but I know about the "unique ID" rule. I'm usign a Jquery validator who check every input by ID (but in this case when I put "xxx[]" the validator check the name of input.) I need a solution in JS/Jquery who works with any number of checkboxes - because this will be updated by SQL. I discover the "minlenght" option - but I need to update this number for each case, and I dont know how. BTW Im trying a solution with class too. Tks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your design is wrong for your needs. You should have separate names for separate checkboxes, as they reflect separate user actions (agreement with a new requirement). This way you will be able, for example, provide unique validation message per checkbox (you may not need this, but still this might a useful future option).

Assuming you have an array of items user should agree with called `itemsToAgree` and validation object where you defined `"agree[]": { required: true }` called `validationObject`, smth like that should work to set up validations:

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemsToAgree.length; ++i) {
    validationObject['agree' + i] = {required: true}
}
```

after that, you have some sort of dynamic mark up generation, I guess. Use names there in the same format as in `validationObject` (agree<x>), and it should work.

I do not know your code, so my solution may be irrelevant in your concrete situation, but I think it anyway provides an approach to follow.

Comment: Hi @MichaelSagalovich! First off all tks for spend your precious time to help me! I dont understand a lot of JS/Jquery - but I "can get by" in most situations. Something like your solutions is what I'm looking for. Its make all sense for me. But I dont know yet how I can put your code with my. I will try here - but if you can help me with this - here is the https://jsfiddle.net/1m93zrft/ - I made a DEMO with 2 text inputs - with validation errors working fine - and 2 checkboxes that will be required. This form will be generated with ASP.

Comment: The checkboxes are dynamic - (this form is for a JOB Opportunity) - and each checkbox is a Job Condition - the employe must agree with all conditions. The ADM can make any condition that he wants. Because of this - I need this solution in JS/JQ - and I think this will be the best way to solve this problem. I can create the checkbox with ASP - counting each box included - and I dont need to change the JS/Jquery - who will work with every number of checkboxes. Tks a lot!! Daniel

Comment: I am sorry, the fiddle is too huge to understand.